# cycles in $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

From the text, I know that , "The set of all permutations of the set {
{ 1, 2, ... , n} will be denoted by $S_n$"

The question is: List all of the cycles in $S_4$

This is my attempt:

$(1,2,3,4)$

$(1,2,4,3)$

$(1,3,2,4)$

$(1,3,4,2)$

$(1,4,2,3)$

$(1,4,3,2)$

$(1,2,3)$

$(1,2,4)$

$(1,3,2)$

$(1,3,4)$

$(1,4,2)$

$(1,4,3)$

$(2,3,4)$

$(2,4,3)$

Comment: How about $(1,2)$? Is $(1)$ a cycle?

Comment: There are $4!=24$ permutations, that is not enough

Comment: @Zelos The problem isn't to find all of the permutations.

Comment: Just add all the $2-$ cycles ;there will $6$ such and your answer will be complete

Answer (score 1):

Start with cycles of length $1$ (there's only one, as $(1)=(2)=(3)=(4)$). Then cycles of length $2$. There are ${4\choose 2}$ of these. We need not consider permutations of our choices, because any $2$ cycle with the same two members is the same cycle.

For cycles of length three there are ${4\choose 3}\cdot \dfrac{3!}{3}$ (number of ways to choose the three things to be permuted, times the number of permutations of those guys, which is $\dfrac{3!}{3}$ since each permutation has three copies of itself, e.g. $(1\ 2 \ 3) = (2 \ 3 \ 1)$). Finally there are ${4\choose 4}\cdot \dfrac{4!}{4}$ cycles of length $4$.

Looks like you're just missing the 2 and 1-cycles.